# CSS form em diagonal sem entortar a letra junto

Tags: css

Olá, preciso fazer um form diagonal. Porém as letras do form ficam tortas juntas "buscar na loja". Alguém consegue resolver isto com CSS?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML Usado

```
<div id="search" class="col-xs-10 search search-form" style="padding-right: 0px;">
        <input class="form" type="search" placeholder="Buscar na loja" name="palavra_busca" style="padding-top: 0px; height: 37px;">     
</div>
```

CSS Usado

```
#search{
-moz-transform: skewX(-40deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(-40deg);
-o-transform: skewX(-40deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(-40deg);
transform: skewX(-40deg);  
}
```

Comment: O que eu já vi sobre isso é que você cria uma DIV com essa formatação e o texto de dentro você aplica a regra mais passando os valores negativos e da certo, agora em um input text não sei se será possível, pois essa propriedade css atribui o o efeito ao elemento em um todo.

Comment: relacionado: [divs lado-a-lado com ponta triangular](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83775/13561)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que fazer o mesmo efeito, mas ao contrário no campo que está dentro. Pra ele ficar reto.

```
#search{
-moz-transform: skewX(-40deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(-40deg);
-o-transform: skewX(-40deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(-40deg);
transform: skewX(-40deg);  
}

#search input{
-moz-transform: skewX(40deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(40deg);
-o-transform: skewX(40deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(40deg);
transform: skewX(40deg);  
}
```

Comment: Faltou o background-color: white no #search

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é dar um id ou uma classe para o texto e modificar de acordo com o que você precisar . Só falta isso . Com a classe form modifica o a font . Acho que é isso que você precisa.

Qualquer dúvida, eu ajudo .